# RSpec double/mock instance variable from initializer

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've got a class where in initializer I need to call instance variable from parsed params:

```
class PrintResults
  include SortResults

  attr_accessor :views_hash

  def initialize(parser)
    @parser = parser
    @views_hash = parser.page_views
  end
```

I want to test attributes accessors, I tried something below:

```
RSpec.describe PrintResults do
  subject { described_class.new(views_hash) }

  describe 'attributes accessors' do
    let(:accessors) { double(page_views: { '/that_70s_show' => ['111.111.111.111'] }) }

    it 'should have views hash' do
      subject.views_hash = accessors
      expect(subject.views_hash).to eq(['111.111.111.111'])
    end
  end
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
  1) PrintResults attributes accessors should have views hash
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.views_hash).to eq(['111.111.111.111'])

       expected: ["111.111.111.111"]
            got: #<Double (anonymous)>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1 +1 @@
       -["111.111.111.111"]
       +#<Double (anonymous)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign your test double directly to the attribute that is returned instead of using the `initialize` method.

Instead of

```
subject { described_class.new(views_hash) }

describe 'attributes accessors' do
  let(:accessors) { double(page_views: { '/that_70s_show' => ['111.111.111.111'] }) }

  it 'should have views hash' do
    subject.views_hash = accessors
    expect(subject.views_hash).to eq(['111.111.111.111'])
  end
end
```

use

```
subject { described_class.new(parser) }

describe 'attributes accessors' do
  let(:parser) { double(page_views: { '/that_70s_show' => ['111.111.111.111'] }) }

  it 'should have views hash' do
    expect(subject.views_hash).to eq('/that_70s_show' => ['111.111.111.111'])
  end
end
```